# problemas carpeta proyecto laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo un proyecto creado con Laravel en la carpeta de mi localhost.
En el navegador abro la carpeta del proyecto, pero no encuentro la carpeta public.
Sin embargo, en mi ordenador si existe dicha carpeta.
Soy nuevo en Laravel y no controlo mucho.
Gracias por anticipado.

Comment: Creo que deberías poner el código que no encuentra la carpeta `Public` así se entenderá mejor la pregunta. Intuyo por dónde vas, pero no estoy suficientemente seguro para darte una respuesta.

Comment: En esta dirección tengo la carpeta del proyecto C:\xampp\htdocs\3salidas. Cree el proyecto así: composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel 3salidas. Lo intento ejecutar con la consola en la carpeta indicada antes mediante el comando: php artisan serve. Me indica que vaya con el navegador a la dirección: http://127.0.0.1:8000. Voy allí y me sale una pantalla en blanco con la siguiente frase: "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he arreglado.
Hay que poner la carpeta en la raíz del localhost.
Además se tiene que ejecutar el proyecto con la consola desde la carpeta del proyecto y ejecutar en el navegador lo que te dice al poner php artisan serve.
Si se tiene Xampp encendido funciona bien.

Comment: necesito ayuda tengo el mismo problema pero no entiendo tu respuesta

Comment: Hola Charly, deberías indicar en la propia respuesta cuáles son los comandos que ejecutaste o cómo quedó el proyecto estructurado (antes y) después de los cambios para que pueda servir de ayuda a otros usuarios también. Lee [answer] para más información.